# python numpy list manipulation

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have the following numpy array:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([2,15,66,180])
```

Now, I would like that the difference between consecutive elements (diff), divided by 25, is always below or equal to one (diff/25 < 0).

```
out = some_function(a,25)
out
```

[2,15,40,65,66,91,116,141,166,180]

**Is there any intelligent pythonic way to do it ?**

Comment: I am confused about what these extra elements in the output array are supposed to be.

Comment: Why isn't the number after 40, 65? So the list should be 2,15,40, 65, 66....?

Comment: how is diff 40, 66 / 25 less than 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy [`arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) function might be of use there, I would do it following way:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([2,15,66,180])
out = np.array([])
for i in range(len(a)-1):
    out = np.hstack((out,np.arange(a[i],a[i+1],25)))
out = np.hstack((out,a[-1:]))
print(out)
```

output:

```
[   2.   15.   40.   65.   66.   91.  116.  141.  166.  180.]
```

This solution assumes a is flat array.

EDIT: After while I noticed my solution produces `np.array` of `dtype float64`, i.e. different that input - depending on your usage it might or not be a issue. For cases when it is problem I reworked my code to following form:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([2,15,66,180])
print(a.dtype) #int64
out = np.hstack([np.arange(a[i],a[i+1],25) for i in range(len(a)-1)]+[a[-1:]])
print(out) #[  2  15  40  65  66  91 116 141 166 180]
print(out.dtype) #int64
```

Code is also shorter, but I left original as it might be easier to understand.

Comment: Wow. Thanks a lot for this great answer !

Answer (score 1):

I have compared the methods of @GGandalf and @Daweo. Intuitively I would have expected to be the `arange` method more performant. But the opposite is the case. GGandalf's solution is 5 times faster.

Not sure if it's important to your use case, but I just found it interesting to point out.

```
import timeit

setup_loop = """
import numpy as np
a = np.array([2,15,66,180])
def loop(a, step):
    b = []
    i = 0
    x = a[i]
    while i < a.size - 1:
        if x >= a[i+1]:
            i += 1
            x = a[i]
        b.append(x)
        x += step

    return b
"""

setup_array = """
import numpy as np
a = np.array([2,15,66,180])
def array(a, step):
    out = np.array([])
    for i in range(len(a) - 1):
        out = np.hstack((out, np.arange(a[i], a[i + 1], step)))
    out = np.hstack((out, a[-1:]))
    return out
"""
print(timeit.repeat("loop(a, 25)", setup_loop, number=100000, repeat=3))
print(timeit.repeat("array(a, 25)", setup_array, number=100000, repeat=3))

>>>[0.687177968943061, 0.6732553936845722, 0.6689018746795448]
>>>[3.5879034464852912, 3.6017167518256006, 3.5779435401398842]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, no great array mathematics, but it it works by incrementing a counter. I hope that's what you meant, because in your question you stated `diff/25 < 0`which should be probably be `diff/25 <= 1`

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([2,15,66,180])

def some_function(a, step):
    b = []
    i = 0
    x = a[i]
    while i < a.size - 1:
        if x >= a[i+1]:
            i += 1
            x = a[i]
        b.append(x)
        x += step
    return b

print(some_function(a, 25))

>>> [2, 15, 40, 65, 66, 91, 116, 141, 166, 180]
```

Comment: Hmm... try:  [3,  15, 139, 287], you can see that the last entry is lost

Comment: just edited the code. Now it should include the last

Comment: Great ! Thanks a lot for your help !